# Equations of motion of the double pendulum by vector methods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I wanted to know if anyone of you do know a book or article on the Internet in which the equations of motion of a double pendulum is deduced, only using vector methods (i.e. Newton's 2nd law as opposed to Lagrangian formalism).

Comment: Unfortunately this question doesn't really abide by either the homework policy or the book request policy... not sure of the best way to make it conform to either though. I recall doing this problem in my system dynamics class, and it was rather unpleasant, but I sold that book years ago so I can't help you with that...

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, at least I can start by looking in system dynamics books. I start to do, however, is quite rude and operations are too, to the point where I lost them and opted for a book or search on the net but just have not found anything. I could upload my procedure and wait for someone to check but it is quite long and not want to take the time to other people with my operations, hehe

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about any physics concept and doesn't fit our book policy.

Comment: "Check my work" type questions would be off-topic too... If you could boil it down to a concept you are struggling with specifically though, that would be on topic. But my guess is you might just be stuck in the algebra because it's fairly tedious. Newton's 2nd law is fortunately "simple," but tedious as anything to keep the signs correct.